# XSLT: How to skip element when specific inner child element is missing?

Tags: xml, xslt

A program I wrote converts periodic measurement data to XML.
Unfortunately sometimes a measurement cannot be made (like being unable to connect) while the program is required to output something (for consistency), so the original value would be `U` for *undefined*.
In that case the converter suppresses output of value when writing XML.

The content model of a sample looks like this (most details skipped):

```dtd
<!ELEMENT sample (label, value?, unit?, thresholds?, range?)>
<!ATTLIST sample
          label CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

So `value` is optional. Some example that has no value (the name of the label is repeated for convenience):

```xml
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
```

When converting that XML to a more specific output format (also XML), I'd like to skip processing of the `sample` nodes if there is no `value` node inside, but I don't know how to do that.

For better understanding, here's the content model where samples occur:

```dtd
<!ELEMENT perf_data (sample+, warn_labels?, crit_labels?)>
<!ATTLIST perf_data
          count CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

At the moment the XSL uses this selector:

```xslt
<xsl:template match="perf_data/sample[@label]">
```

So actually the context for the example would be (but I think it's not very important, and I'm showing two samples here):

```xml
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
```

Just using `match="perf_data/sample[@label]/value"` breaks the transformation.

### Another example

As people wanted a longer example, I try to give one (manually minimizing the input and the XSLT):

The top-level element is:

```dtd
<!ELEMENT MonitoringOutput (description? , exit_code? , status_string? ,
          info_string? ,  perf_string? , perf_data?)>
<!ATTLIST MonitoringOutput
          id CDATA ""
          version CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Other elements of interest:

```dtd
<!ELEMENT label (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST label>

<!ELEMENT range EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST range
          min CDATA "0"
          max CDATA "0">
```

And an example would be (here `std_dev` has no `value`):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MonitoringOutput id="id-18895" version="0.2">
  <perf_data count="3">
    <sample label="last">
      <label>last</label>
      <value>0.508798</value>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="std_dev">
      <label>std_dev</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="avg">
      <label>avg</label>
      <value>0.508798</value>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
</MonitoringOutput>
```

The extra XSLT selectors are (hopefully complete):

```xslt
<xsl:template match="/MonitoringOutput[@version]">
  <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="name(.)"
  /> v<xsl:value-of select="@version" /> id=<xsl:value-of select="@id"
  /> (PRTG.xsl v0.0.2)</xsl:comment>
  <xsl:variable name="main.node" select="." />
  <prtg>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="perf_data[@count &gt; 0]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$main.node/perf_data"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <Error>1</Error>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </prtg>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="perf_data[@count &gt; 0]">
  <!-- no parsing error -->
  <xsl:variable name="main.node" select=".." />
  <xsl:variable name="perf.node" select="." />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$perf.node/sample"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="perf_data/sample[@label]">
  <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample/label">
  <Channel><xsl:value-of select="."/></Channel>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample/range[@*]">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
    <xsl:comment>range: <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />="<xsl:value-of
    select="."/>"</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample/value">
  <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please create a well formed sample input with each condition (empty or not); your current XSLT and sample desired output to allow us to more clearly understand your desire.

Comment: For a similar question someone had complained that the given example contained too many lines, so I tried to focus: If I provide more input, you probably want more XSL and more DTD, too. And someone might complain that it's all unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: All we need is the shortest way to reproduce the problem - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it suffices to add an empty template `<xsl:match="perf_data/sample[not(value)]"/>`. Or add the condition for the `value` in the existing template e.g. `<xsl:template match="perf_data/sample[@label and value]">`.

As for your added, more complex sample, I still think that adding the empty template suffice i.e. if you have both

```
<xsl:template match="perf_data/sample[@label]">
  <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="perf_data/sample[not(value)]"/>
```

then `sample`s with no `value` will not produce any output (and you don't need to change templates matching `value` or `sample/value` or `sample/value`).

Comment: I have to related questions: (1) if I have selectors for children of `sample` (like `<xsl:template match="sample/label">`), do I have to adjust those, too, or is there an elegant way to skip processing of children when the parent is skipped? (2) How would the selector look like if `value` would not be a direct child of `sample`, but "somewhat further down"?

Comment: @U.Windl, see whether the edit helps (at least for (1)), for (2) I would think that it might be just `<xsl:template match="perf_data/sample[not(descendant::value)]"/>` that needs to be added but let's not add variants of input to a question once it has been asked and answered.

Comment: OK, adding an "ignoring match" worked, but I realized another issue: If all `sample`s were skipped, I'd have to output something else (call it "error message") as the output would be empty otherwise. However I have no idea "how to match on output".

Comment: @U.Windl, you really need to ask new questions on follow-up issues: you can of course higher up have e.g. `<xsl:template match="perf_data[not(sample/value)]">error message: not a single sample with a value</xsl:template>`.  Matching on "output" is not possible directly in any XSLT version (with the exception of some XSLT 3 stuff like https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#conditional-content-construction, it is of course possible to use different transformation steps (where one step processes the output of the previous), this is straight-forward in XSLT 2 and later, needs exsl:node-set() in XSLT 1.

Comment: I know, but thinking again, my previous question and you answer might have solve that already: Similar as the solution for this question, a search for descendants might allow a similar solution. It's still a long way to go, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **minimal** example you could use as a guide:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/MonitoringOutput">
    <xsl:variable name="perf_data" select="perf_data[@count > 0]" />
    <prtg>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$perf_data">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$perf_data/sample[value]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Error>1</Error>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </prtg>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sample">
    <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="range/@*"/>
        <Channel>
            <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
        </Channel>
        <Value>
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </Value>
    </result>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="range/@*">
    <xsl:comment>
        <xsl:text>range: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)" />
        <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:comment>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Instead of applying templates indiscriminately to all `sample` elements, and then "catching" those without a `value` with an empty template, this simply applies templates selectively to  `sample` elements that do have  a `value`.

Applied to your input example, this will return:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prtg>
  <result>
    <!--range: min=0-->
    <Channel>last</Channel>
    <Value>0.508798</Value>
  </result>
  <result>
    <!--range: min=0-->
    <Channel>avg</Channel>
    <Value>0.508798</Value>
  </result>
</prtg>
```

Comment: I see: You moved the selection criterium from template `match` to `template-apply`'s `select`. I didn't think about it before.

Comment: Indeed, I prefer to close the barn door *before* the horse has bolted.