# XSLT: selecting a node where non of its children do have given properties (i.e. ¬∃ (∄))

Tags: xpath, xslt, match

I think it would be counter-productive to repeat all the code from [XSLT: How to skip element when specific inner child element is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77008424/6607497) when asking another question about it:

In the example shown there are `result` elements populated with data from each (valid) `sample`.
However if there is no valid sample at all, nothing is created.
The condition for a valid sample is `[@label and value]`.

What I'm looking for is a match criteria if none of `<xsl:template match="perf_data/sample[@label and value]">` matches; "¬∃" so to say.
Such match could be used to create an error output for example.

The basic XSL pattern seems to be "*if exists, then forall matches do ...*", but I need "*if not exists, then do ... once*".

I imagined the solution would be similar to `<xsl:template match="[not(boolean(./sample/@label) or not(./sample/value))]">`, but that does not work as intended.

So is it possible, and if so how?
I had spent quite some time to find such solution, but failed...

Software being used is `xsltproc` from `libxslt-tools-1.1.28`; I have no idea which version of XSLT it supports.
It says:

```text
Using libxml 20904, libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20901, libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817
libxslt 10128 was compiled against libxml 20901
libexslt 817 was compiled against libxml 20901
```

Comment: Have a look at the 1st template in my answer to your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77015187/3016153. Do note that it is not possible to create output using a template that does not match anything in the input. You must do this in a template matching some ancestor node.

Comment: Maybe it was confusing: I edited the question to point out that I tried to handle it for `perf_data`, and not for `sample`.

Comment: It's an *example*. It shows how you can apply templates to a set of nodes OR output an error merge message if the set is empty. P.S. If you want to make your question clear then include a [mcve] instead of asking us to switch back and forth between pages.

Comment: You don't say what XSLT version you are using. In XSLT 3.0 there is an instruction `xsl:on-empty` which seems to be suited to your needs.

Comment: `libxslt` supports XSLT 1.0 (+ several EXSLT functions).

Answer (score 1):

You can do e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="perf_data[not(sample[value|@label])]">error message: not a single sample with a value or label</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it did not work. Also: Doesn't `sample[value|@label]` mean "a `sample` that *either* has a `value`child, *or* a `label`attribute"? However that should be *and* instead.