# How to propagate information from inner elements to outer element?

Tags: xslt, match

For the content model described in [XSLT: How to skip element when specific inner child element is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77008424/6607497), I have a new question:

I need to create different output on the outer level, depending on matching an inner level.
For example, consider this part:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
<!-- ... -->
```

There are two `sample` elements, but none of those contains a `value` element, effectively making them useless.

I wrote a rule to "verbosely ignore" such elements, like this:

```xml
<xsl:template match="perf_data/sample[@label and not(value)]">
  <xsl:comment>Skipped incomplete sample "<xsl:value-of select="label"
  />"</xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

However what I also need is *if **all** `sample` elements are ignored*, then I have to create an extra outer element on output (maybe `<Error>1</Error>`), and otherwise `<Error>0</Error>` at the "`perf_data` level".

However I have no idea how to implement that, specifically as you cannot have a counter in a variable; otherwise I'd imply count the valid `sample`s and check the count.
How could I do that?

See also [XSLT: selecting a node where non of its children do have given properties (i.e. ¬∃ (∄))](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77022483/6607497).

## Sample Inputs

Here are two input sample, a good one, and a bad one:

### Bad Sample

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MonitoringOutput id="id-3150" version="0.2">
  <description>snmp_netif-1.out</description>
  <exit_code>0</exit_code>
  <status_string>Previous state not found, U octets/s in [delta 0s], U octets/s out [delta 0s]</status_string>
  <perf_string> in=U;;;0 out=U;;;0</perf_string>
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
</MonitoringOutput>
```

### Good Sample

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MonitoringOutput id="id-3160" version="0.2">
  <description>snmp_netif-2.out</description>
  <exit_code>0</exit_code>
  <status_string>bond0</status_string>
  <info_string>1560.23 octets/s in [delta 10s], 350.921 octets/s out [delta 10s]</info_string>
  <perf_string> in=1560.23B;;;0 out=350.921B;;;0</perf_string>
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <value unit="B">1560.23</value>
      <unit>B</unit>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <value unit="B">350.921</value>
      <unit>B</unit>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
</MonitoringOutput>
```

So the absence of `<value>` in all `<sample>`s should be propagated "up" to the processing of `<perf_data>` which should be considered empty or non-present then.

Comment: If you do this in a template matching the parent `perf_data`, you can count how many `sample` children satisfy the condition. Then you can do something if all (or none) do, and another thing if some do. Alternatively, you can store the results of the processing in a variable, then count the nodes in the variable before passing it to the output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9608675/6607497 says you cannot use XSLT variables for counting.

Comment: I am afraid you are completely missing my point. If you have a variable that contains the **processed nodes**, you can then count e.g. how many comments are in the variable, using the `count()` function. Apparently you are thinking in terms of procedural language, counting by incrementing a variable in a loop. That's rarely required (though still possible)  in a functional language like XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

```
Do you mean something like this 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/Document[not(perf_data/sample[not(@label and not(value))])]">
    <Error>1</Error>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="perf_data[sample[@label and not(value)]]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <Error>0</Error>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If we have this xml:

```
<Document>
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <range min="0"/>
      <value/>  <!-- value-element present -->
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
</Document>
```

This xslt will give this result

```
<Document>
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <Error>0</Error>
  </perf_data>
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <range min="0"/>
      <value/>
    </sample>
    <Error>0</Error>
  </perf_data>
</Document>
```

If we have this xml:

```
<Document>
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
  <perf_data count="2">
    <sample label="in">
      <label>in</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
    <sample label="out">
      <label>out</label>
      <range min="0"/>
    </sample>
  </perf_data>
</Document>
```

it will give this result:

```
<Error>1</Error>
```

Comment: Your skills with XSL are much better than mine, I see. Actually I had worked out a solution that is somewhat more complicated, but for completeness, I'll provide it here, too.

Comment: Unfortunately your XSLT does not work correctly for the bad example I just added to the question: I get `perf_data` output *and* `<Error>0</Error>` inside.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to handle the situation like this (thanks to the hint given by [michael-hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k)):

```xsl
<xsl:template match="/MonitoringOutput[@version]">
  <xsl:variable name="main.node" select="." />
  <Prtg>
  <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count($main.node/perf_data/sample[value]) = 0">
        <xsl:comment>(no valid sample)</xsl:comment>
        <Error>1</Error>
        <!-- ... -->
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="perf_data[@count &gt; 0]">
        <xsl:comment>(non-empty perf_data)</xsl:comment>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$main.node/perf_data"/>
        <!-- ... -->
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:comment>(empty perf_data)</xsl:comment>
        <Error>1</Error>
        <!-- ... -->
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </Prtg>
</xsl:template>
```